# how do i create a geospatial view in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, geospatial

What is an geospatial view? How do I create geospatial view using angularjs from json and csv files?

Is it some kind of library or geo-representation of data on a world map?

Comment: There is GeoJSON data format which is supported almost by every popular GIS Mapping library/API, Google maps API, MapBox and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You may find ng-map quite useful for displaying geo-json overlaying a map: https://ngmap.github.io/#/!geojson.html

In the example shown you can load in geojson data like so:

```
<ng-map zoom="4" center="39.02, -95.81">
<map-data on-click="vm.onClick()"
load-geo-json="us-states-20m.json">
</map-data>
</ng-map>
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for hopefully you find it helpful!